# SBT: Run an action on all projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT project that contains multiple subprojects, i.e.:

```
> projects
[info] In file:/home/me/src/foo/
[info]     popen
[info]     foobar-core
[info]   * foobar-client
[info]     foobar-db
```

Is there a way to run an action in each of these subprojects? I'm looking for something like `publish-all`, since I currently go through all the subprojects and run `publish` manually, which gets fairly tedious once there are more than a handful of subprojects.

I'm using `sbt-0.11.2` out of inertia, but am willing to upgrade if that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a project that aggregates all the other projects. Each action run on this project will be run on all aggregates. Here is an example from the [sbt wiki](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "hello",
                            base = file(".")) aggregate(foo, bar)

    lazy val foo = Project(id = "hello-foo",
                           base = file("foo"))

    lazy val bar = Project(id = "hello-bar",
                           base = file("bar"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: URL amended since the guide has moved

Comment: This gets repetitive if you have many projects. Is there a way to list all the defined projects in the build?

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Kim Stebel works perfectly, but requires an aggregation project.

**(The following solution is tested with sbt 1.3.x)**

I wanted a more dynamic solution. We have a small sbt plugin, that is used in all our projects anyway. So I added this:

```
val allProjects = Command.single("allProjects"){ (s,task) =>
  val extracted = Project extract s
  import extracted._
  import currentRef.{ build => curi}
  val build = structure.units(curi)
  build.defined.keys.map(projectId => s"$projectId/$task").foldRight(s)(_ :: _)
}

  override def globalSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    List(
      commands += allProjects,
      ...
    )
  }
```

For a single `build.sbt` just use the first part with the line `commands += allProjects` added

This creates the command `allProjects` and can be used like `allProjects compile`.

The execution happens sequential, so it is blocking.

## Better try this

After digging a bit more, I found out, that if no project with path `.` is created, all projects are by default aggregated in the root project.

Our problem was, that we liked our root project to be named, so we defined it as

```
lazy val coolProjectName = project.in(file("."))
```

I changed this in the build.sbt to:

```
name := "coolProjectName"
```

This way the default aggregation is still working.
And commands/tasks on aggregated projects are executed in **parallel**.